# How to set OpenVPN client bind address?

Tags: openvpn

The OpenVPN client machine has two interfaces to Internet: a low-speed and high-speed one. Default route goes throught the low-speed one. I'd like OpenVPN to connect to server through the high-speed one. How can that be done?

Like in ping, I can use "-I 1.2.3.4", or in telnet "-b 1.2.3.4" and then the 1.2.3.4 IP is used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `local` directive to force the client to use a specific IP address.

> --local host
>   Local host name or IP address for bind. If specified, OpenVPN will bind to this address only. If unspecified, OpenVPN will bind to all interfaces.

You can specify it in the client config file too

```
local ip.add.re.ss
```

Comment: You may also want to read [this](https://forums.openvpn.net/topic10922.html) and it's [linked document](http://kindlund.wordpress.com/2007/11/19/configuring-multiple-default-routes-in-linux/)

Comment: How would you use this when the client gets its IP for the desired interface via DHCP?